# Image saved on iPad is Letterboxed either side

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiimageview, swift4

When I save an image from a simple camera app on the iPad it creates a letter-box shaped image. That is, a black bar on either side. Saving on the iPhone does not do this.
Where should I look in my code to correct this?

edit:
This is my code for saving. It seems to be alright? I hear what you are saying, but I can't see a fix. It saves the image, just not a wide image on the iPad.

```
    func saveToCamera() {

    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video) {
        stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { (CMSampleBuffer, Error) in

            if let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(CMSampleBuffer!) {
                if let cameraImage = UIImage(data: imageData,scale: UIScreen.main.scale) {

                    // ------------------- Do Shutter Blink -------------------------
                    let blinkWidth = cameraImage.size.width
                    let blinkHeight = cameraImage.size.height
                    print("Blink Width: \(blinkWidth)")
                    print("Blink Height: \(blinkHeight)")

                    // do actual shutter simulation
                    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: blinkWidth, height: blinkHeight))
                    let shutterView = UIView(frame: rect)
                    shutterView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                    self.view.addSubview(shutterView)
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                        shutterView.alpha = 0
                    }, completion: { (_) in
                        shutterView.removeFromSuperview()
                    })

                    //Do shutter sound
                    let cameraShutterSoundID: SystemSoundID = 1108
                    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(cameraShutterSoundID)
                    // -------------- end of blliink and shutter sound ---------------------

                    // Actually save the combined photo
                    if let nImage = self.drawCirclesOnImage(fromImage: cameraImage, targetSize: CGSize.zero) {
                        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(nImage, nil, nil, nil)
                    }

                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If image is not saved properly to disk that means image is corrupted. While saving the image specify the format. Also if you are adding certain properties like alpha or gray or white colors you should verify. In Imagepicker Controller call back check for proper data and try to set image to some imageview. Your call back is not saving data properly.